# substring in awk command

Tags: awk, substring

I am using an awk command :

```
df -Pk | grep /var/prod/data | awk '{q=sprintf("%c", 39); print "INSERT INTO entity_trend(entity_name,entity_type,run_date,count) VALUES (\47DISKSPACE\47,\47SPACE\47,SYSDATE,"$5");";}' > cmd.sql
```

So, the contents of cmd.sql will be :

```
INSERT INTO entity_trend(entity_name,entity_type,run_date,count) VALUES ('DISKSPACE','SPACE',SYSDATE,**52%**);
```

Instead , I want :

```
INSERT INTO entity_trend(entity_name,entity_type,run_date,count) VALUES ('DISKSPACE','SPACE',SYSDATE,**52**);
```

How should I form the substring command ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `+0` to get rid of the `%`: `$5+0`

```
awk '{q=sprintf("%c", 39); print "INSERT... SYSDATE,"$5+0");";}' > cmd.sql
                                                       ^^
```

See an example:

```
$ echo "55%" | awk '{print $0}'
55%
$ echo "55%" | awk '{print $0+0}'
55
```

Comment: Well it is just the fact that doing an arithmetic operation makes `awk` "convert" the string into a digit, so that the `%` gets stripped.

Comment: Also, feel free to accept the answer if you issue is solved :)